# German (?) film from 1970s with reporter with artificial eye camera following a dying person

Tags: story-identification, movie

Very vaguely remembering this, in a world where there's no incurable disease left, a reporter follows a last dying person (who maybe refuses treatment for some reason?), without them knowing. They maybe fall in love. (?)

The reporter has an eye replaced with a camera, to constantly record / broadcast this. The two go into some lowtech run-down areas (because maybe in the "normal" part of the world the sick person would get the treatment forced on them maybe?). Literally can't remember their genders even, except that they were of opposite genders.

There was a scene where the reporter's eye was replaced, I think in some kind of a chair, as a fairly quick procedure. The eye looked like a normal eye from afar.

Think it's from the 1970s. Think it's German. It probably looked like a low-budget film, definitely nothing like a blockbuster. That's about all I can remember. Thanks.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum will do, though I really don't remember practically anything else. Not even the genders of the two, believe it or not (except they were of opposite genders).

Comment: I'm guessing that you do know more than you're telling us. For example, was the reporter male or female? What was the name of the actor or character they played? Was it in colour or black-and-white? Was the "eye cam" shown as a POV shot at any point? Did the camera eye just look like a normal eye? What was the budget like on the film? What disease did the main character have?

Comment: I found it by searching for **sci fi movie "reporter" "eye replaced"** on google. The first result was this one; https://www.nytimes.com/2021/03/25/movies/bertrand-tavernier-dead.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is [*Death Watch*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081182/) (1980). This film was released in Germany as *'Der gekaufte Tod'*

> In a future where dying of illness is exceedingly rare, a terminally ill woman becomes a celebrity and a man with camera implants goes to secretly record her for a morbid TV show.

Comment: looks like it. thanks a lot! will wait with the accept for a little while. how did you find it? I tried googling, nothing relevant has come up.

Comment: Aha.  Based on [*The Unsleeping Eye*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8146) by D.G. Compton.  I thought it sounded familiar. :)

Comment: and in France as "Le Mort en Direct" apparently. (like, "Death (in) Live (broadcast)").